# How to search for certain strings of text in a column and output a certain word?

Tags: python, pandas

Looking to search for multiple strings of text in a pandas dataframe column. When that certain string is found, then the program should output a certain word.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel(OriginalFile.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
category = []

for row in df['THINGS']:

    if df[df['THINGS'].str.contains('APPLE', na=False)]:
        category.append('RED')
    elif df[df['THINGS'].str.contains('GRASS', na=False)]:
        category.append('GREEN')
    else:
        category.append('NoCat')

df['category'] = category
print(df)
```

Above is what I had tried. Appreciate the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['THINGS'].str.contains('APPLE', na=False)
m2 = df['THINGS'].str.contains('GRASS', na=False)
df['GRASS'] = np.select([m1, m2],['RED','GREEN'], default='NoCat')
```